# starting MySQL from python script

Tags: python, mysql, unix, python-3.x, python-3.4

Im trying to start mysql server from python 3.4 script on Max OS X 10.10.4
yet I don't know how to pass the super user password ?

```
import os 
os.system("sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start")


Sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 3):

You are currently going in the right direction. In my system a `mysql` server is started from `/etc/init.d/mysql`.

Just use the following code snippet to run your `mysql` server from a python script.

```
import os

os.system('sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start')
```

The best way to run the `root` commands will be to execute the file itself as `root`

Simply type `sudo python script.py` in your shell and you can replace `os.system('sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start')` 
with 
`os.system('/etc/init.d/mysql start')`

Comment: thanx Arpit, the problem that to use any sudo command u have to pass the super user password !

Comment: There is still some error in this. Wait I will fix it... this worked because I already once specified the sudo password in the same terminal. Hence it did not ask for the sudo password again. Let me get back to you with the fix.

Comment: I would suggest running the script as root.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows OS, first you have to get Administrator authentication and then you can run command line commands using subprocess to start MYSQL80 service.

```
import pyuac
import sys

def startDB():
    import subprocess as sp
    sp.Popen("net start MYSQL80")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        try:
            pyuac.runAsAdmin()
        except:
            sys.exit()
    else:        
        startDB()
```